# Can't get styling working on redirected page

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have setup my site for all requests to go through index.php

My current .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My site structure is based on MVC so it looks at the url for controller, action and optional id.

I would like to rewrite requests to the news section for friendly urls.

In the first instance I would just like to get this working with the News ID.

So instead of going to news/article/1 I would like it to go to news/1

I have tried the following rules but can't seen to get it to work.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news/article.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news/article/$1
```

This rule shows the correct page however all styling is removed.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$ /news/article/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What are actually your current CSS/JS links?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules look correct, don't forget the `[L]` flag at the end of the `RewriteRule` lines.

The reason you had no styling when using

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$ /news/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

is probably because you forgot to set the CSS/Javascript source URLs and any images to contain  absolute paths, otherwise they'll try loading from within the `article` directory.

Comment: I've double checked the urls for css and they are set as absolute paths.

Comment: @Stephen I copied the wrong RewriteRule into my answer originally. Does it work with the one in my answer now? In the Network tab of your Developer Tools (hit F12 in Chrome/Firefox) are the CSS/image resources loading right?

Comment: No It only works with RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$ /news/article/$1 [L] However, css is still not showing. The css is loading ok.

Comment: Also no other links on the site work now other than those within news

Comment: Do you only have 1 htaccess file? Are `news` and `news/article` real directories?

Comment: only one .htaccess file. news is real directory but article is a php page.

Comment: And is article.php in the top level directory or in the news directory?

Comment: yes it is.  I am assuming it is to do with how I am routing my views.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44634/discussion-between-jon-and-stephen)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by re-routing all requests for News Articles in my Controller.